# file_get_contents full page source using php

Tags: php, html, file-get-contents

I use `file_get_contents();` to get full source page for a website. Sometimes there are some content like 'product details' or 'reviews' that not showing until you click on button. is there any way to get these content?

my simple code.

```
$str1= file_get_contents("https://www.google.com");
echo $str1 ;
```

Comment: _"is there any way to get these content?"_ Not really. You'd have to emulate all the JavaScript AJAX hits. You're probably better off using a browser testing tool like Selenium. Or better still, using an API provided by the host.